# Text box only allow IP address in windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I need a textbox that only allows an IP address. I can create this in a web application but i can't do this in windows application. Please help me to do this..

Comment: try this [IP-TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11576/IP-TextBox)

Comment: so... it's a Windows application (Winforms, WCF, Silverlight) or a Web Application (ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, ...) ... witch one is, cause ***ASP.NET Windows Application***, is kinda confusing...

Comment: Edited according to comment on Darren's question (removing asp.net).

Comment: BTW: It's 2014 --> I'd better talk of "IPv4 address" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method to validate IP

```
 public bool IsValidIP(string addr)
    {
        //create our match pattern
        string pattern = @"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.
([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$";
        //create our Regular Expression object
        Regex check = new Regex(pattern);
        //boolean variable to hold the status
        bool valid = false;
        //check to make sure an ip address was provided
        if (addr == "")
        {
            //no address provided so return false
            valid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //address provided so use the IsMatch Method
            //of the Regular Expression object
            valid = check.IsMatch(addr, 0);
        }
        //return the results
        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator`:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
                                ErrorMessage="This expression does not validate." 
                                ControlToValidate="yourTextBox"     
                                ValidationExpression="RegEx here" />
```

Then set the `ValidationExpression` to: (Only allow IP Addresses)

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\
```

Comment: @Amulraj you can use the yourTextBox_Validating event to capture this and then use the Regex I provided.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here.
Take the text, split by dots, if you end up with 4 bytes (as in, 0-255 ranged numbers) it's a valid ip.

```
bool IsTextAValidIPAddress(string text)
{
    bool result = true;
    string[] values = text.Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None); //keep empty strings when splitting
    result &= values.Length == 4; // aka string has to be like "xx.xx.xx.xx"
    if(result)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
            result &= byte.TryParse(values[i], out temp); //each "xx" must be a byte (0-255)
    return result;
}
```

Or, if you can/want to leverage `System.Net`

```
bool IsTextAValidIPAddress(string text)
{
    System.Net.IPAddress test;
    return System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(text,out test);
}
```